# elsif statements not working in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need help understanding the usage of elseif statements in the view for Rails. I have done it before but now I am doing it with SLIM and I can't seem to get it to work. I want it to print out the word "him" or "her" depending on the current user `gender`. The code I am using is printing out the elsif statement in text.

```
            a.profile_btn href="#" data-mfp-src='#ask_me' 
              img alt="" src="/assets/login_icon2.png" /
          if current_user.gender == "male"
              span Ask Him Out
          elsif current_user.gender == "female"
                span Ask Her Out
```

The original code:

```
            a.profile_btn href="#" data-mfp-src='#ask_me' 
              img alt="" src="/assets/login_icon2.png" /
              span Ask This User Out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
- if current_user.gender == "male"
   span Ask Him Out
- elsif current_user.gender == "female"
   span Ask Her Out
```

Comment: This makes nothing appear, so the space where the text should appear is blank. It's not showing in the page source either.

Comment: Its probably because your user's gender doesn't match either `male` or `female`. Check the case and spelling